# Displaying serial data of python in the web

Tags: python, serial-communication

I have the following program of python which displays serial data in the command prompt.

```
#!python
import time
import cgi
from serial import Serial
import subprocess

ser = Serial('COM4', 115200, timeout=1)
print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

while True:
    # Read a line and convert it from b'xxx\r\n' to xxx
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')[:-2]

    if line:  # If it isn't a blank line
        print(line)
        if line == '520':
            subprocess.call(["xte", "key Up"])
        elif line == '620':
            subprocess.call(["xte", "key Down"])
        elif line == '110':
            break

ser.close()
```

**This program is running perfect. The data is being constantly displayed in the console. Basically it is displaying the distance from a ping sensor I want to display the data in the web page `http://localhost/distance.html`. How will I do it? Displaying only the last data will be fine.  Thanks for all the suggestions**

Answer (score 0):

Write the data to a file. Serve that file with a webserver like for example Apache.

Comment: Writing to the file and reading from the file will not give continuous updates.

Comment: @SubhenduSinhaChaudhuri: You didn't say anything about continuous updates in the question. But if you want that, use an HTML file and put a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">` in the header, and it will refresh once a second. If you want anything more continuous than that it's going to be quite complicated.

Comment: Thank for that suggestion . But how will i get the data. Please help with a little code . I am really stuck. I want to show the data in a small box

Comment: @SubhenduSinhaChaudhuri: Your code above gets the data, so I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. Do you know how a webserver works? Do you know what HTML and HTTP is?

Comment: @SubhenduSinhaChaudhuri: Change your script to write out an HTML file. Serve that file with a webserver like for example Apache.

Comment: Please help me in that matter. I donot know how to do that

Comment: @SubhenduSinhaChaudhuri: First you need to learn HTML, so you can make a simple static HTML page. Then you need to set up a webserver, like Apache, to serve that HTML page. Once you have that working, the rest is trivial, although you probably want to use a template system in Python, but that's for later. But I can't teach you how to do any of this through comments on Stackoverflow. You have to learn that yourself, by reading manuals and tutorials.

Comment: I alraedy have Apache , have a static web page . Then i can't go further as i have no knowledge of Ajax etc..

Comment: @SubhenduSinhaChaudhuri: You don't need that. You just write a Python script that *writes to a static page*. Done! It's that easy!